# What would be the most efficient solution to syncing stopwatch timers between the back-end and front-end?

Tags: websocket, frontend, httprequest, backend

This question isn't meant for a specific stack, but more of a general question.

I have a front-end application where users are able to create multiple stopwatch timers and run those timers simultaneously to keep track of their tasks. I need to sync the stopwatch data from the front-end to the back-end. What would the best way be to achieve this?

I'm looking for a solution that keeps the front-end and back-end timer attributes in sync as much as possible while consuming as few resources as possible.

I'm able to think of 2 solutions:

1. *HTTP requests based on events and polling, for example, if the user pauses the timer, a PUT request gets sent to the back-end with the updated timer attributes. And for the timers that aren't paused, a PUT request gets sent every minute.
   An issue with this is that if there are 1000 users and each of them has multiple stopwatch timers running, this will be a lot of requests.
   Another issue is that if the page gets refreshed before a PUT request, then the timer information will, of course, be lost until the last put request.*
2. *Web sockets- I haven't worked with web sockets before, so I'm not sure how viable it is for my scenario. But from what I understand the timer table on the database can be updated in real-time from the front-end once a connection is established to the back-end. Currently, I'm unaware of any downsides to this. If there are any downsides to web sockets, please let me know.*

In summary, I'm trying to update multiple timers from the front-end to the back-end, however, I'm not sure if web sockets or HTTP requests would be the best approach for minimizing the resources being used while also keeping the timers as accurate as possible.
I'd like to hear some opinions from other developers on which the better approach would be better, and possibly other solutions.